# C# Is there any other way of opening web shortcuts

Tags: c#, browser, hyperlink

Im currently using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(link);
```

to open web links on a dropdown menu in a program for work. However, the security suite on the works computers do not allow this to function. I have spoken with IT and they will not relax the security policies on this.

I've had a search and most of the posts suggest the way I have already done it.

We use IE in work.

Is there another way of opening links?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can launch IE directly from Process start with a url as a parameter like:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Cheers,

CEC

PS: additional possible solution: *BRIBE THE IT DEPARTMENT*, good food is often a working solution to IT dept. problems.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what is being blocked?

Comment: I guess the Process.Start is blocked (the application is not run in a trusted environment)

Comment: As I read the question it is the access to launch the link (the internet shortcut) that is blocked not the Process.Start invocation.  It would be impractical block Process.Start (if not impossible...)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm not sure exactly what is being blocked, but I will try this way and let u know.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an embedded browser window? If so, embed the browser window into your C# application and open the link in that window. If not, the starting of the process may not help you because the security suite may prevent this as well.

Comment: I have thought about this, but some of the web applications I'm linking to require security certificates to run. Could it get complicated using this?

Comment: You shouldn't be in trouble if certificates are valid. You may be in trouble if certificate is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a ProcessStartInfo object with the UseShellExecute property set to false? This may have a chance of circumventing the security restriction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx

Comment: Thanks, will look into this if first suggestion doesnt work for me